# Accessing a dataframe inside a package in R

Tags: r, dataframe

The dataframe CHAIN is defined in the package "mi"  in R.

I would like to access it without having to open/attach.

Is it possible to reference it from outside ?
What would be its fully qualified name ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data(CHAIN, package = "mi")
```

will load it in for you without needing to load 'mi'.  Now you can just refer to it as CHAIN.

Comment: Thank you. I realize that my question was bigger. I also want this data to be in a proper variable, and not modify a 'context'. I'll repost a question